# Сreate an object with a function and return the object in JS

Tags: javascript

How can I make the object-output with function?
This is for the reducer of react-redux.

output:
{
reducer: {
AA:BB
}
}

```
const objectCreator = {...}
objectCreator(AA,BB)
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are AA and BB? Are they strings? Functions? You haven't defined `objectCreator` as a function. It's just an object. You really need to add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. According to your title you need `() => ({});` if you mean “create _by means of a_ function”, or `() => ({ f(){} });` if you mean “object _which contains a_ function”. How is React Redux related to this, specifically? The example code looks like you may need `const output = objectCreator(AA, BB);` and `const objectCreator = (AA, BB) => ({ reducer: { [AA]: BB } })`. Familiarize yourself with how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).